# Large Amount of Finger Pressing One UIButton Causing Other UIButtons to Have Dead Zones

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I've come across an interesting issue in Xamarin IOS that's a bit hard to explain, but it's just not making sense. Basically what I have are UIButtons lined up vertically down the screen on the left and right sides. If I am to touch and hold a button on the left side of the screen with a large amount of my finger, 2 or 3 of the buttons on the right side of the screen on the edge side create these dead spaces that prevent them from being clicked unless pressed leading more towards the center. The same thing happens if I am to hold a large amount of my finger on a button on the right side of the screen, where the left side buttons create this same dead space near the edges.

Now, if I just hold with a normal to small amount of my finger surface, I have absolutely no issue.

Nothing is blocking them from being clicked when a large finger surface area is used, and I'm just wondering if there's some sort of method that controls the surface area that one can use with a UIButton.

Comment: sounds like a hardware limitation of the touchscreen and/or the multitouch decode logic

Comment: Are you able to see what the touch state is? Im sure if you are touching a large part of the screen in a non conventional, they phone may possibly think it is your face and cancel the touches.